# Change background of Windows Store app Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps

I need some help. I'm a new programmer, and I've created a Windows Store application in visual studio 2013. The problem is that I don't know how to change the background of a blank page. I want to set a png image as background, but I really don't know how to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add your Image inside App.Xaml inside the Resources,

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="PageBg" TargetType="Grid">
          <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/yourImage.png"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

In your Page's grid, Just set like this,

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"  Style="{StaticResource PageBg}">
</Grid>
```